# Configuring a pydantic model that leaves field values unchanged if it would have caused a ValidationError?

Tags: validation, pydantic

For example...suppose I have the code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: dict
    c: str

User(**{"a": "2", "b": "gibberish", "c": "ok"}).dict() # should give {"a": 2, "b": "gibberish", "c": "ok"}
```

Is this achievable with Pydantic? I've tried defining custom validators (w/ all sorts of configurations...using pre=True, root validators w/ or w/out pre=True, etc) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/discussions/4284, this is not easily configurable via Pydantic V1. The only option (according to the author themselves) is to define custom data types and call the validators directly and then catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [construct](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#creating-models-without-validation) to create models without validation:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: dict
    c: str


user_dict = User.construct(**{"a": "2", "b": "gibberish", "c": "ok"}).dict()
print(user_dict)  # {'a': '2', 'b': 'gibberish', 'c': 'ok'}
```

Comment: But I do want validation...with the caveat that for fields whose values would cause an error, I would like those fields to be "unchanged". Using constructors would not be helpful here.